# Create sub folders and sub_sub folders for several folders

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create two subdirectories in multiple directories.

For example, I have:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
```

and I would like to create in each of them:

```
Folder1
   Sub_Folder
      Sub_sub_Folder

Folder2
   Sub_Folder
      Sub_sub_Folder

Folder3
   Sub_Folder
      Sub_sub_Folder
```

I tried:

```
for dir in *; do mkdir $dir/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder/; done
```

Without success, does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the '-p' option of the `mkdir` command:

```
for dir in *; do mkdir -p $dir/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder/; done
```

`mkdir` usually only creates a single folder. With the `-p` option, it also creates the parent folders needed.

Alternatively, you can do a double mkdir:

```
for dir in *; do mkdir $dir/Sub_Folder; mkdir $dir/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder; done
```

Comment: `*` will glob to all files. Use `*/` for directories only. Quote `$dir` and just to be sure: `mkdir -p -- ...`.

Comment: It worked very well thanks you ! Now in contrary, do you now how to delete all these sub folders and sub sub folders created in each folders ?

Comment: @bewolf Change mkdir by rmdir to do the opposite.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I explained my reasons in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201112/create-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-for-several-folders#comment95229161_54201177).

Comment: @mickp: ok, I understand that the answer is not perfect; yet it's very easily salvageable (what I usually do in this case is just silently edit the answer to add the missing quotes and fix the glob) `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it, try the following:

```sh
for dir in */; do mkdir -p "$dir"/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder/; done
```

It is important to add the forward slash so that you only match directories and not files, hence: `*/`.

> Man page for [mkdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html)
>
> `-p`, `--parents`: no error if existing, make parent directories as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the directories for which you want to create subdirectories and their names follow a pattern like in your example, you can use brace expansion in Bash:

```
mkdir -p Folder{1..3}/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder
```

This expands to

```
mkdir -p \
    Folder1/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder \
    Folder2/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder \
    Folder3/Sub_Folder/Sub_sub_Folder
```